# compare columns and generate duplicate rows in mysql (or) python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, union

i am new to Mysql and just getting started with some basic concepts. i have been trying to solve this for a while now. any help is appreciated.

I have a list of users with two phone numbers. i would want to compare two columns(phone numbers) and generate a new row if the data is different in both columns, else retain the row and make no changes.

The processed data would look like the second table.

Is there any way to acheive this in MySql. 
i also don't minds doing the transformation in a dataframe and then loading into a table.

```
   id  username  primary_phone  landline
    1      John            222       222
    2   Michael            123       121
    3      lucy            456       456
    4  Anderson            900       901
```

[image: after processing]

Thanks!!!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: stackoverflow makes it hard to paste table data. it enforces conversion to image. i dont mind changing the data, but is there a way?

Comment: You can past text data and then add 4 spaces for correct format

Comment: Something like this would be best- `df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'username':['John','Michael','lucy','Anderson'],
                   'primary_phone':[222,123,456,900],'landline':[222,121,456,901]})`

Comment: yeah, but i wanted to solve in mysql. i did not want to question to look like a python question. Only when if its not possible in Mysql i would want to take the pandas approach

Comment: that's fine, this is for your reference so that in future you can get quicker response since it is easier for reader to answer quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove `variable` column and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.melt(['id','username'], value_name='phone')
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .drop_duplicates()
        .sort_values('id'))
print (df)
   id  username  phone
0   1      John    222
1   2   Michael    123
5   2   Michael    121
2   3      lucy    456
3   4  Anderson    900
7   4  Anderson    901
```